# Not all input fields working with jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am working with jQuery validate and for some reason my rules for the inputs description and down do not work.

The only error in the console I get is for my validate file, which is jQuery's, version 1.14.0.

```
Uncaught TypeError: e[d].call is not a function
ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: e[d].call is not a function
```

However, I believe I had this error before I added the rules for the description down. Am I doing this correctly or does jQuery only have set rule names that you can use? If that is the case, would I have to make new rules to do this and how would I do that.

The inputs name-company work, why do the ones below it not work?

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on" method="POST" id="project-information-form">
        <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
        <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="title-roll" name="title" placeholder="Title/Role">
        <input type="email" class="input-borderless" id="project-email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="number" class="input-borderless" id="project-number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-company" name="company" placeholder="Company/URL">
        <textarea rows="3" class="input-borderless" id="project-description" name="description" placeholder="Describe the project"></textarea>
        <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-source" name="referral" placeholder="How did you hear about us?">
        <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-socialMedia" name="social" placeholder="Which of our social media influenced you the most?">
        <input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-humanTest" placeholder="Human Test: What day comess after Thursday?">
        <input type="submit" id="submit-project" class="submit-project-button" value="Send Project Inquiry">
    </form>
 $(function() {

   var iSelected = 0;
    var ranges = [{
      lower: 500,
      upper: 1000
    }, {
      lower: 1100,
      upper: 2000
    }, {
      lower: 2100,
      upper: 5000
    }, {
      lower: 5100,
      upper: 10000
    }, {
      lower: 11000,
      upper: 20000
    }, {
      lower: 21000,
      upper: 50000
    }, ];
 var wslider = $("#sliderBar").width() / (ranges.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
   var range = $('<div class="rangedot"><div class="intervalCircle"></div></div>');
   var left = (100 / (ranges.length) * i);
   rangeleft = "calc(" + left + "% - 2px)";
   range.css({
     left: rangeleft,
     width: wslider
   });
   range.on("click", function(idx) {
     return function() {
      iSelected = idx;
       var sliderleft = wslider * idx;
       $("#sliderInterval").animate({
         left: sliderleft
       });
       $("#budgetAmount").text("$" + ranges[idx].lower.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + " - " + "$" + ranges[idx].upper.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
     };
   }(i));
   $("#sliderBar").append(range);
   $("#sliderInterval").css("width", wslider + "px");
 }
    //$("#sliderInterval").show().text("BUDGET");
      $("#budgetAmount").show().text("$500 - $1,000");

//Send the project email
    $("#submit-project").on("click", function(event) {
        //event.preventDefault();

      var project_name = $("#project-name").val();
      var title_roll = $("#title-roll").val();
      var project_email = $("#project-email").val();
      var project_number = $("#project-number").val();
      var project_company = $("#project-company").val();
      var project_description = $("#project-description").val();
      // var range_selected      =  iSelected;
      var range_upper = ranges[iSelected].upper;
      var range_lower = ranges[iSelected].lower;
      var project_source = $("#project-source").val();
      var project_socialMedia = $("#project-socialMedia").val();
      var project_humanTest = $("#project-humanTest").val();
      all_focused = [];
      $('.project-option-boxes.box_focused').each(function() {
        all_focused.push($(this).text());
      });

      $("#project-information-form").validate({
            onfocusout: true,
            rules: {
              name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
              },
              title: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
              },
              email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
              },
              phone: {
                required: true,
                digits: true,
                minlength: 10
              },
              company: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
              },
              description: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
              },
              referral: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
              },
              social: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
              }
            },
            messages: {
              name: {
                required: "Please enter your name",
                minlength: "Your name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
              },
              title: {
                required: "Please enter your title",
                minlength: "Your title seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
              },
              email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
              },
              phone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                digits: "Please enter a valid phone number",
                minlength: "Your number seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
              },
              company: {
                required: "Please enter your company or url",
                minlength: "Your company/url seems a bit short. Please enter at least 2 characters"
              },
              description: {
                required: "Please enter your Project Description",
                minlength: "Your description seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
              },
              referral: {
                required: "Please enter how you heard about us",
                minlength: "Your response seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
              },
              social: {
                required: "Please enter which social media platform you know we are on",
                minlength: "Your social media source seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
              }
            },
            //To allow the validate to work as typing
            //onkeyup : true, 
            submitHandler: function(form) {
```

Comment: you really should address the error first.  it's telling you something is wrong, and unless you know what's wrong, you can't say it's not causing the problem you're posting about.

Comment: The error is coming from the jQuery validate file though? I am calling out to it. I just don't see or know how to check for that error. It is around this in the file `gnore)&&e[d].call(c,this,b)}this.lab` ... where `e[d].call` is.

Comment: The error is coming from the JQuery validate file because something is wrong with your code.  You could debug by commenting out various parts until you find what part is causing the error.

Comment: @devlincarnate I believe the error was referring to this `onfocusout : true,` ... I commented it out and it still isn't validating the rest of this.

Comment: I was suspecting onfocusout.  True is not valid.  It must be a function.  To troubleshoot the validation not working, try commenting out the fields your trying to validate (process of elimination).  For example, comment out all fields except the first one that isn't working.  Does it work when it's the only field?

Comment: @devlincarnate I tried commenting out each individual input (rules and messages code) for the ones not working and that did not help. Then I tried commenting out the company input rule and message (the input right above the ones not working) and all that did was stop the validation for that input.

Comment: what's the value of iSelected ?

Comment: @devlincarnate I can rule that out immediately. I just added that before posting this question and this problem has been occurring for about a week.

Comment: I ran `debugger;` right before ` $("#project-information-form").validate({` and did not get anything to show up in the console. I am not sure how I would enter `debugger;` into the rules/messages without getting a token error.

Comment: I'm trying to set up a JS Fiddle so I can debug your code.  What is the value of iSelected?

Comment: @devlincarnate updated my question with the full code that includes the value of `iSelected`.

Comment: I stripped out the slider stuff and it works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/87synxt4/    You can see how I've used console.log() to track and verify values.  I recommend you do something similar to pinpoint the problem in the code that I didn't include in my demo.

Comment: As per docs, `onfocusout` can only be set to `false` or an over-riding function, and "`true` is not a valid value".  Since this option is enabled by default, you would not declare it.  The same goes for `onkeyup`.  Please review the documentation.

Comment: @devlincarnate What in the slider code was making this not work?

Comment: If you compare the demo link I posted a few comments above with the code you posted in your question, you can see what I omitted.  I don't know if that is the cause of your problem or something else in your code that you haven't shown.  I do know the core of what you're attempting to do with the validation works fine.

Comment: @Paul - that's for you to determine.  Use some basic debugging strategies to narrow down your issue.  Commenting out blocks of code and using console.log() will lead you to the problem.  I'd start by commenting out the slider code and see if that does the trick.  If it does, go line by line through that slider code and re-enable to see what triggers the problem.  Sorry there is no magical answer here.  But this is often how "mysterious" problem need to be addressed.

Comment: @devlincarnate Definitely understand. I've tried commenting out the slider code and it reloads the page for some reason on submit.

Comment: I've also tried adding in your `console.log(form);` and it doesn't log anything into the console.

Comment: if you don't see anything at all, it means that code isn't being hit.