# Creating a basic human test validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to create a simple validation check. I have an input that asks the user to enter the day after Thursday. So, if the user does not enter "Friday", I do not want my form to process and an error message to show up. I am unsure if I am doing the right. In addition, I have jQuery validate on this same page and for this same form, so I am unsure if there is a way I can create it within the validate, to make things consistent.

Here is what my javascript looks like so far, but I am getting an error. Please see jsfiddle in the comment below.

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on" method="POST" id="project-information-form">
<input type="text" class="input-borderless" id="project-humanTest" placeholder="Human Test: What day comess after Thursday?">
<input type="submit" id="submit-project" class="submit-project-button" value="Send Project Inquiry">
</form>


function humanTest () {
$("#submit-project").on("click", function(event) {
if( document.getElementById(project-humanTest).val === 'Friday') {
 alert("Correct");
} else {
  alert("Sorry you are wrong.");
}
})
}
```

Can I add this basic valdiation check to jQuery validate or if not, how can I make this work so it checks to see if "Friday" was entered.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=urFKoEAgrH

Comment: So if I enter "friday" it won't match? This is case-sensitive. Did you mean it to be?

Comment: @Nikki9696 No, I don't want it to be case sensitive.

Comment: See jQuery validate `required` that uses function ... do test of lower case in that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no available rule/method for the jQuery Validate plugin, you would simply write your own using [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customRule", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || value === params[0];
}, "Please enter the correct value");
```

Then declare it within `.validate()`...

```
$('#project-information-form').validate({
    rules: {
        "project-humanTest": { // < MUST be the NAME of the field
            required: true,
            customRule: ["Friday"]
        } ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7gxnpba2/1/**

**Note**:  the `this.optional(element) ||` part ensures that the field will remain *optional* when using only this one rule by itself.  In other words, if you left this bit out and declared only this one rule on the field, then the field could never be left blank.  You'll always have the option of adding the `required` rule to the field whenever you want it required.

---

Can also be made case-insensitive:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customRule", function(value, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.toLowerCase() === params[0].toLowerCase();
}, "Please enter the correct value");
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/7gxnpba2/**

Comment: Great, thanks! Will this be case sensitive or is there a way I can make it where it isn't case sensitive? Then, can I just not include this: `}, "Please enter the correct value");` and create a message like the other rules?

Comment: @Paul, yes.  If you define a message using the `messages` object within `.validate()` method, it will over-ride the message from `.addMethod()`.   You could even leave it out of `.addMethod()`, but risk an error if you forget to define it within `.validate()`.  See my edited answer for a case-insensitive version and demo.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It all makes sense. I didn't have any idea how to create my own rule before. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with the code you posted. Let's look at them.

1. While not inherently a problem, you are mixing vanilla javascript with jQuery in the second and third lines.
2. In vanilla javascript, there is no val() function natively, that is something provided by jQuery. So in order to use it, you must access it from a jQuery object. EX: `$('#project-humanTest').val()`. For what it's worth, to do the same thing in vanilla JS (which you've started to do) you would do something like `document.getElementById('project-humanTest').value`
3. You are not preventing the default click action on your submit button. This would result in your custom validation code likely not getting a chance to fire before the form is submitted wherever it is ending up. Make sure to try something like the following when you are creating custom click events on submit buttons:

   ```
   $('#submit-project').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     // continue code from here
   });
   ```

Now we need to tie this all together. Without seeing a bit more about your form setup, I can't say that this will definitely work, but it should give you an idea of where you start.

```
$('#submit-project').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if( $('#project-humanTest').val().toLowerCase() !== 'friday' ) {
    alert('That is not the correct day. Try again');
  } else {
    $(this).submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: I have more of the code posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728871/not-all-input-fields-working-with-jquery-validation?noredirect=1#comment59140231_35728871 ...  Thanks for your help so far. I am just confused how I would tie it all together with jQuery validate.